# How to Compare many cells and get the results

Tags: excel, vba

I have tried using AND & OR method in IF conditions, But I could not get any results.

Now in second row there are three actual & expected data I have to verify all the three actual and expected data and give it has pass or fail. I have to repeat till the last row. I have found the last row but not able to find the solution for first problem statement.
Attaching screen shot for reference.
I have to paste the result has pass or fail in the U column

[image: This Image has the table content]

Comment: Please edit your question to show what you tried, and explain what the specific problem was.

Comment: How would you, as a human, determine pass/fail? It's not at all clear to me. Please also share you current code so we have a starting point.

Comment: `three actual & expected data` Are you sure it is `three` instead of `four` on screenshot?

Comment: The main problem here is I need to compare the actual and expected and give result. Now here we have to check D2&E2 cell and get the result. Then we have to repeat the same for I & J, N &O, S & T. Now with these results I have to give result in U if all the conditions are satisfied I will enter has Pass.. If any one conditions gets failed it should be fail. ...    Hope this  works for you all

Comment: @JNevill I have written a VBA code for 3000lines where I am pulling data from different workbook and sorting the data on destination workbook. Now after pulling the data i have to compare the columns and get the result in U column as I mentioned in above column. Which code u need in specific so that I can share my code here!!

Comment: Hi @taller, Thanks for correcting me yea it four not three.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

equation in u2

```
=if(and(d2=e2,i2=j2,n2=o2),"pass", "fail")
```

[image]

Comment: Hi Aly Thanks for sharing but I have already tried using AND function but in the final stage the result is fail.

Comment: This works too. I like it.

Comment: Hi Aly it worked. I used it in this way.

Destination.Range("AQ4") = "=IF(AND(D4=E4,I4=J4,N4=O4,S4=T4,X4=Y4),""Pass"", ""Fail"")"
    Destination.Range("AR4") = "=IF(AND(AC4=AD4,AH4=AI4,AM4=AM4), ""Pass"", ""Fail"")"
    Destination.Range("AO4") = "=IF(AQ4=AR4, ""Pass"",""Fail"")"

Answer (score 1):

The below code worked for me. Thanks all for your help.

```
Destination.Range("AQ4") = "=IF(AND(D4=E4,I4=J4,N4=O4,S4=T4,X4=Y4),""Pass"", ""Fail"")"

Destination.Range("AR4") = "=IF(AND(AC4=AD4,AH4=AI4,AM4=AM4), ""Pass"", ""Fail"")"

Destination.Range("AO4") = "=IF(AQ4=AR4, ""Pass"",""Fail"")"
```

Answer (score 0):

Create columns to compare and enter the formula below as in your example. You'll get a True or False. Then compare those columns etc... Paste the formula down the columns.

```
=D2=E2
```

[image]

As I said, you then have to compare those columns.

```
=IF(F2=TRUE, IF(I2=TRUE, IF(L2=TRUE, "Pass", "Fail"), "Fail"), "Fail")
```

[image]

Comment: Hi Nick, Thanks for sharing. But I need to compare multiple cells to get the result. Pls look at the above mentioned comment

Comment: If none of these solutions work, then you have some spaces or other characters besides 'N' and 'Y'. Maybe some 'N ' or ' N'.

Comment: Hi Nick, Thanks for the help it worked